# Need not+adjective+to infinitive

Tags: sentence

Can we use adjective like in this example or we always need to use infinitive without 'to' after auxiliary 'need'?

1. We need not required to fill the form.

Comment: That should be restructured: *We need not **be** required to fill **out** the form.* And it could be rephrased to omit **to** like this: *Filling out the form need not be required*.

Comment: Good..Thank you

Answer (score -1):

There something wrong. "Need" is here use as a semi-modal; it is called a semi-modal because it is not built with "to" and has no past form ([ref.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/grammaire/grammaire-britannique/need#need__48)). It is not constructed with adjectives then, but with verbs and the infinitive without "to" is used for these verbs.

[image]

Unless used in a formal or literary context the negative form of this semi-modal is written "needn't" ([ref.](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/needn%27t)).

[image]

The correct sentence.

- We needn't require them to fill the form.

Comment: What are the wrong things? I mean need is an auxiliary verb here. And your second example ' cans of soup needn't be kept in the fridge' also uses 'be' as main verb.

Comment: @Rocky  Only the use of an adjective instead of "modal+ bare infinitive". Anyway, the correction brought to the sentence turns it into something possibly different from what you intended;  as the comments show, the insertion of "be" gives it another meaning. "Several" is maybe not a good choice (I must have thought "adjective" instead of "bare infinitive" and "missing 'to'".)

Comment: You can say "you needn't ***be*** required to fill out a form," or you could say "you needn't require ***somebody*** to fill out a form, but you can't say "you needn't require to fill out a form" because *require* needs an object. [See Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/require).

Comment: @PeterShor Right, I see that now; thanks for telling me.